# TextView display "<" string in string.xml perform not correct layout in arabic language

Tags: android, xml

i want to use "<1" this string in strings.xml.

```
<string name="smaller_string">&lt; 1</string>
```

this works correct and shows "<1" correct, but in arabic language (from right to left) the "<" is on the top of "1", the `TextView` width is `wrap_content`.

It's really tricky, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create **layout direction - specific** recource sets by appending the **`ldrtl`** suffix for right-to-left locales. To do what you need, create a **`values-ldrtl`** resource directory with another **`strings.xml`** file inside and overwrite your string resource there, so it displays the expression properly:

```
<string name="smaller_string">1 &gt;</string>
```

This applies to any resource, so you can redefine them for specific cases like right-to-left layout directions.

Edit: if you want it to be specific only to arabic language, use the **`-ar`** suffix.

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)